# Navigate to another screen on notification click using Ionic 2

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using the [Local Notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) plugin for Ionic 2 to deliver local notifications in my app. When users click on the notification, the app opens the main screen and should navigate to an info screen.

```
localNotifications.on("click", function(notification) {
    this.navCtrl.push(InfoPage);
});
```

The notification displays and the click event is fired, but I am getting the following error:

```
exeption nativeEvalAndFetch : TypeError: undefined is not an object 
                              (evaluating 'this.navCtrl.push')
```

I am assuming that the NavController has not loaded yet so is undefined when the method is called, but I'm not sure. Is there a trick to getting this to work?

Comment: imported infopage in main page?

Comment: @varunaaruru Yes, if I link up a button and navigate to that page it works, just not from notification.

Comment: I solved it, the problem was to do with the `this` keyword accessing the wrong scope. Removed it and it works now.

Comment: super..write the solution as answer and close it when you have time ..it might help others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily fixed by removing the `this` keyword:

```
localNotifications.on("click", function(notification) {
    navCtrl.push(InfoPage);
});
```